# How to implement Self Referencing pivot table relationship with Eloquent

Tags: database, orm, eloquent, lumen, erd

I have this scenario to be implemented

[image]

**"Member - Album"** many to many relationship is the comments. Member can post comments on any Album. Album can have comments from any number of Members. Some comments can be posted as a reply to other comments.

"reply_to" refers to the parent comment. That is, a comment can have several replies.

[image]

I'm using Eloquent and Lumen 5.5 in my project. I have gone through the documentation of both of these. I know how to implement relationship such as M:N, M:1 and etc.

I still couldn't find out how to implement this scenario using Custom Intermediate Table Models in Eloquent. Any help is much appreciated.

Note: I have removed other elements from the ERD to make it simple..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand.
Below are the relationships required in the model.\

`Comments model`

`Comment::belongsTo('Member'); //add namespace of member model` 
  `Comment::belongsTo('Albums'); //add namespace of member model`

`Member model`

`Member::hasMany('comments');`

`Album model`
  `Album::hasMany('comments');`

For not getting `reply to`comments you can add where in `Comment::belongsTo('Albums')->whereNull('replyTo');`

Then can fetch reply comments via comment id.

Comment: Comment table is a pivot table or  Intermediate Table (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). You haven't used that here.

Comment: There is no need of a Pivot table, it can be achieved without that.

Comment: I know it can be achieved without that. I want to use Pivot table in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Member
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment:class, 'Member_id'); // a member may has many comments
    }
}

class Album
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'Album_id'); // an album may has many comments
    }
}

class Comment
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class, 'reply_to'); // self reference
    }

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'Member_id'); // a comment should belongs to a member
    }

    public function album()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Album::class, 'Album_id'); // a comment should belongs to an album
    }
}
```

Querying:

```
Album::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['parent', 'member]);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Comment table is a pivot table or  Intermediate Table (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). You haven't used that here.

Comment: Looking at your table screenshot, `Comment` table is not a pivot table. Relation both to `Album` and `Member` is `1:N`, not `N:N`. Think about it, a comment should belongs to a member, not belongs to multiple members. **Imagine if this comment belongs to you and me.** Also this comment should belongs to a post not multple post. **Imagine if this comment also exists in another post / answer (kinda wierd).** Anyway, have you tried my answer?

Comment: Here I'm trying to use pivot tables to implement the solution.In your solution, you are not handling the "self-referencing".

Comment: `Comment::parent` method is your friend. To get self reference: `$comment->parent` (will return another `Comment` object if any).